# element.appendChild() giving unexpected result: removes existing children

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a 'photos' page on a website. It uses PHP to retrieve the filenames in a directory, and then attempts to create divs (with images in them) programmatically with javascript. However, when I try to create 'w3-third' divs, edit the innerHTML so that it embeds an image, and (the problematic step) add them to the 'w3-row' div, it removes the existing children. Hence, there is only one image per row.

I have been looking for alternate code / solutions, but the element.appendChild() function seems to be the only method; I have tried element.children.push(), but element.children is an [HTMLCollection] which (I guess) is read-only.

```
$.getJSON("content/photospage/get_filenames.php", function(data){
    var photoFileNames = data;
    console.log(photoFileNames.length + " images to display.");
    var photosDiv = document.getElementById("divPhotos");
    for(var i = 0; i < photoFileNames.length; i += 3){
      console.log("Loop! i=" + i);
      var newRow = document.createElement("div");
      newRow.classList.add("w3-row");
      newRow.classList.add("w3-padding-8")

      var newImg1 = newImg2 = newImg3 = document.createElement("div");

      newImg1.classList.add("w3-third")
      newImg2.classList.add("w3-third")
      newImg3.classList.add("w3-third")

      newImg1.innerHTML = "<img src='" + dir + photoFileNames[i] + "' class='w3-round w3-margin-bottom constrained'>";
      newRow.appendChild(newImg1);
      console.log("displayed img " + (i))
      if(i+1 < photoFileNames.length){
        newImg2.innerHTML = "<img src='" + dir + photoFileNames[i+1] + "' class='w3-round w3-margin-bottom constrained'>";
        newRow.appendChild(newImg2);
        console.log("displayed img " + (i+1))
      }
      if(i+2 < photoFileNames.length){
        newImg3.innerHTML = "<img src='" + dir + photoFileNames[i+2] + "' class='w3-round w3-margin-bottom constrained'>";
        newRow.appendChild(newImg3);
        console.log("displayed img " + (i+2))
      }

      console.log(newRow.children);

      photosDiv.appendChild(newRow);
    }
```

The html element that exists by default:

```html
<div class="w3-container w3-content w3-center w3-padding-32 " id="divPhotos">
</div>
```

Sorry for the large amount of code above. Thanks for any assistance, and I'm happy to clarify anything that I failed to mention. :)

Also, I am aware that the code is clunky and inefficient, so let me know if you pick up on anything I could do better. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With

```
var newImg1 = newImg2 = newImg3 = document.createElement("div");
```

you've created *one* object (an `HTMLDivElement`) in memory, which 3 variable names (`newImg1`, `newImg2`, `newImg3`) refer to. You do not have 3 separate elements. When you call `appendChild` with one of the elements, you remove it from wherever it previously existed in the DOM.

Since you want separate elements, you should do so explicitly:

```
var newImg1 = document.createElement("div");
var newImg2 = document.createElement("div");
var newImg3 = document.createElement("div");
```

You could make the code less repetitive by using another `for` loop instead of creating separate standalone elements:

```
for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
  const thisIndex = i + j;
  if (thisIndex >= photoFileNames.length) {
    break;
  }
  const img = document.createElement("div");
  img.innerHTML =  "<img src='" + dir + photoFileNames[thisIndex] + "' class='w3-round w3-margin-bottom constrained'>";
  newRow.appendChild(img);
}
```

Comment: Woah, thank you! Should've seen that! It's always the way: trying to be clever always creates more problems